# Как переменной присвоить значение json из отдельного файлы или с удаленной страницы

Tags: javascript, json

Есть такая задача:

"Данные для списка доступны в формате JSON по адресу https://neto-api.herokuapp.com/etsy"

Есть два варианта:

1. Создать файл и перекопировать туда содержимое json, потом достать
   данные из этого файла, но я не знаю как это сделать. Очень
   интересно. Но я хочу воспользоваться следующим вариантом.
2. Прямо с удаленной страницы получить нужные данные.

Как это сделать, подскажите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
fetch('https://neto-api.herokuapp.com/etsy')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

`data` - полученный JSON из файла удалённо `//fetch() не работает в IE`

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!